# Failed to instantiate service.FileService Constructor threw exception;

Tags: java, spring-boot

> --------------this is my file service-------------------- i am using spring boot 2.2.2

```
@Service  public class FileService {

    public final Path fileStoreLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileService(File file) throws FileStorageExecption {
        this.fileStoreLocation= Paths.get(file.getFile_path()).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        try{
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStoreLocation);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

                throw  new FileStorageExecption("--------Create directories exception-------");

        }
    }


    public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) throws FileStorageExecption {
        String fileName= StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            Path targetPath=this.fileStoreLocation.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(),targetPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return fileName;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
               throw new  FileStorageExecption("---------Cann't copy file----");


        }
    } }
```

> ----------this is my file controller----------

```
 @RestController
 public class FileController {
    @Autowired
    FileService fileService ;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/file/upload")
    public String fileUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws FileStorageExecption {
            fileService.storeFile(file);
        return "ok";

    }

}
```

> --------------------so Failed to instantiate fileService with this error--------------------  Error starting ApplicationContext. To
>   display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug'
>   enabled. 20-01-19 Sun 12:49:32.308 ERROR SpringApplication Application
>   run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'fileController': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'fileService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'fileService' defined in file
>   [/media/hp/2FFE0BC66362754F/project/AndunaEchoMedia/target/classes/lk/andunaechomedia/service/FileService.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [lk.andunaechomedia.service.FileService]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
>     at lk.andunaechomedia.Fire.main(Fire.java:10) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'fileService' defined in file
>   [/media/hp/2FFE0BC66362754F/project/AndunaEchoMedia/target/classes/lk/andunaechomedia/service/FileService.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [lk.andunaechomedia.service.FileService]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:314)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
>     ... 19 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [lk.andunaechomedia.service.FileService]: Constructor
>   threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:310)
>     ... 32 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(UnixPath.java:77)   at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.(UnixPath.java:71)  at
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:281)    at
>   java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)    at
>   lk.andunaechomedia.service.FileService.(FileService.java:22)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200)
>     ... 34 common frames omitted
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have you declared file bean in spring configuration?

Comment: No how to do it

Comment: Yes i declared it.. File DAO class

Comment: I followed https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/

Answer (score 0):

Constructor of `FileService` should have `FileStorageProperties` and not `File`.

```
@Autowired
public FileService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
```

Comment: no fileStorageProperties class is POJO class my POJO class name is File

Comment: I have an error  spring boot configuration annotation process not  config in my File Class with annotation @ConfigurationProperties

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your comment. Could you please rephrase?